# Add content type "document" or "document map" to existing document libary

Tags: document-library, content-type

I want to add the content type "document" or "document map" to existing document library and get following error message.

> Conflict while saving
>
> The changes you make are in conflict with the same time by another
>   user changes made. In order for your changes to take effect, click
>   your web browser's " Back " button to update that page and submit your
>   changes again.